# Here the word "meaning" is qualifying which subject?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, participle-phrases

An English teacher uses this kind of sentence:

> We all know the first meaning of the word *kite* that is what you flew yesterday, but we also use the word **meaning** a kind of bird.

My confusions are:

> 1. Is the phrase *meaning a kind of bird* is a PARTICIPIAL phrase?
> 2. If it is then which subject is it qualifying-- *we* or *kite?*

**Note: As it was spoken so I am not sure if there was a comma before "meaning".**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's an ***adverbial*** "participial phrase" modifying the verb ***use*** (specifying ***how, the way*** we use the word "kite").

Note that idiomatically, most native speaker would say *we use the word **to mean** a kind of bird*.

---

Even though you've only heard it *spoken*, I'm sure you didn't hear a pause between "word" and "meaning" - in which case there's no comma (since to a first approximation that's the *only* reason to use commas).